# Outdated forgeGradle?

Tags: java, gradle, minecraft

I want to make a mod for, Minecraft 1.12.2 but seems as the old Gradle doesn't exist anymore, and just creates the stuff for versions over 1.13, any idea on how to fix it or where can I get the old version for 1.12?
anytime I want to do:

```
./gradlew setupDecompWorkspace --debug
```

I get:

```
23:22:09.986 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
23:22:09.987 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
23:22:09.987 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
23:22:09.987 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Task 'setupDecompWorkspace' not found in root project 'forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2859-mdk'.
23:22:09.987 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
23:22:09.987 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
23:22:09.988 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.  Run with --scan to get full insights.
23:22:09.990 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
23:22:09.991 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
23:22:09.993 [WARN] [org.gradle.internal.featurelifecycle.LoggingDeprecatedFeatureHandler] 
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
23:22:09.993 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] 
23:22:09.993 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 20s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... after lots of days investigating I found a version that allows me to work propperly I downloaded here:
https://github.com/DaRealTurtyWurty/Tutorial-Mod

and their version worked fine, but after some investigation I'm dumb and I'm not supposed to compile with eclipse, I must use ./gradlew build, and that will start creating the mod.

so... the solution was the version provided by turtywurty, and dont use eclipse, and better use visual studio code.

[image: turtywurty's example mod compiled]